# Aiogram3 edit audio message. Python3

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Оправляю ботом сообщение.

```
audio = FSInputFile(path=f"./Audio/EN/{data[2]}.mp3", filename=data[2])
await bot.send_audio(audio=audio, chat_id=user_id, title=data[2], reply_markup=data[1], caption=data[0])
```

Затем по нажатию inline_key, срабатывает callback-функция с изменением сообщения.

```
await bot.edit_message_media(InputMediaAudio(media=FSInputFile(f"./Audio/EN/Start.mp3"), caption=text),
                                 user_id,
                                 message_id=message_id)
```

НО! Название аудио дорожки меняется, как и всё сообщение, а вот само аудио- остается прежним. То есть получается обновленное сообщение со старой аудиодорожкой. Как обновить саму аудиодорожку?

Все варианты перепробовал.